# How to replace word or character in listbox vbnet?

Tags: vb.net

Hi all I need to remove and replace word or character in listbox with button.

Example:
char1cter
char1cter
char1cter

Output
character
character
character

Answer (score 0):

Once you set a string equal to a ListBox item, you can alter a string a number of ways:

```
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Use StringBuilder, more efficient for long strings >200
        Dim badString As String = "Char1cter"
        Dim aStringBuilder As New StringBuilder(badString)
        aStringBuilder.Remove(4, 1)
        aStringBuilder.Insert(4, "a")
        badString = aStringBuilder.ToString()
        MsgBox(badString)

        'Use Remove/Insert at specific locations
        badString = "Char1cter"
        badString = badString.Remove(4, 1).Insert(4, "a")
        MsgBox(badString)

        'Use .Replace, but first test if there is a 1 anywhere in the string
        badString = "Char1cter"
        If InStr(badString, "1") Then
            badString = badString.Replace("1", "a")
            MsgBox(badString)
        End If

        'Use .Replace w/o testing for a 1
        badString = "Char1cter"
        badString = badString.Replace("1", "a")
        MsgBox(badString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you ever need to loop through each character in a string, it can be done by using e.g.:

```
Dim newString as String = ""
For Each ch As Char In badString
  If ch <> "1" Then 
     newString &= ch
  Endif
  If ch = "1" Then 
     newString &= "a"
  Endif
Next
```

Comment: Looks weird to me, this answer as well as the question. You don't want to replace some characters in the dropdown but within the underlying data you used as source for the dropdown. And then it is just string manipulation over a collection of strings.

Comment: `Buff = ListView1.Items(i).Text` won't compile.

Comment: In the first place a String is an array of Char. In the second place we are talking about a ListBox not a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over all the items in the listbox, inserting a changed one and removing the broken one:

```
        For i as Integer = 0 To listBox1.Items.Count - 1
            listBox1.Items.Insert(i, listBox1.Items(i).ToString().Replace("char1cter", "character"));
            listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i+1);
        Next i
```

Comment: Is not only character
Example:
worldword
internetworld
exampleworld

Output
World
Internet
Example
....

Comment: So modify the code I gave.. I'm no mind reader; I cannot know all the different replacements that you want to do, and your question didn't mention them either

Answer (score 0):

I would go for an approach that already corrects it when loading the data, maybe something in this style:

Somewhere your faulty data come in:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class OriginalDataProvider

    Public Shared Iterator Function GetData() As IEnumerable(Of OriginalRecord)
        Yield New OriginalRecord(1, "Char1cter")
        Yield New OriginalRecord(2, "Seco1d")
        Yield New OriginalRecord(27, "Thir1")
    End Function

End Class
```

and the class that defines the record:

```
Imports System

Public Class OriginalRecord

    Public Sub New(id As Int32, label As String)
        Me.ID = id
        Me.LabelWithErrors = label
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property ID As Int32

    Public ReadOnly Property LabelWithErrors As String

End Class
```

Then you need a wrapper that corrects the records:

```
Imports System

Public Class CorrectedRecord

    Public Sub New(originalRecord As OriginalRecord)
        If (originalRecord Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(originalRecord))
        Original = originalRecord
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property ID As Int32
        Get
            Return Original.ID
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Label As String
        Get
            'Your sophisticated solution comes here (I just replace "1" through "a" which does not work for all my strings but as I don't have 
            'a clue what your logic is take it as an example)
            Return Original.LabelWithErrors.Replace("1"c, "a"c)
        End Get
    End Property

    Private ReadOnly Property Original As OriginalRecord

End Class
```

And on the Form on load event you just bind to the corrected records:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, args As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.DataSource = (From e In OriginalDataProvider.GetData() Select New CorrectedRecord(e)).ToArray()
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Label"
End Sub
```